# How do you get md:NameIDFormat to appear in the SAML2 Metadata output?

Tags: owin, saml-2.0, identityserver3, shibboleth, sustainsys-saml2

I have my SAML2 "working" (authentication: success) but shibboleth isn't sending me any claim data, I need *just* the users email :)

The shibboleth people are telling me to add **this** to my SAML2 metadata... it's very clearly not there.

```
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-
format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
```

We're using the OWIN middleware from https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/ to get this all to work, but it's pretty stock config?

```
        additionalProviders["saml2p"] =
                (IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType, AuthenticationProviderElement config) =>
                {
                    var opt = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
                    {
                        SPOptions = new SPOptions
                        {
                            EntityId = new EntityId("https://my.site.ca")
                        },
                        SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                        AuthenticationType = "saml2p",
                        Caption = "MySite",
                        Notifications = new Saml2Notifications()
                        {
                            AcsCommandResultCreated = (result, response) =>
                            {
                                var claimsIdentity = result.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                                //None of this exists in the result
                                var userEmail = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "User.email");
                                var userFirstName = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "User.FirstName");
                                var userLastName = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "User.LastName");
                            },
                            LogoutCommandResultCreated = commandResult =>
                            {
                                // Post logout URL
                                commandResult.Location = new Uri("/login", UriKind.Relative);
                            }
                        },
                    };

                    Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.GlobalEnableSha256XmlSignatures();

                    opt.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
                      new EntityId("https://their.site.ca/shibboleth-idp/shibboleth"),
                      opt.SPOptions)
                    {
                        LoadMetadata = true
                    });

                    app.UseSaml2Authentication(opt);
                };

        return additionalProviders;
```

TL;DR; md:NameIDFormat not in SustainSys SAML2 metadata output

Answer (score 0):

The config on my end was correct, the problem was the config in shibboleth not sending the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier claim back.